# Should I use Patterns and Practices for SharePoint 2013 On Prem and stick with it for Branding

Tags: design-patterns, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

The idea behind remote publishing of Patterns and Practices looks very good at best but I am having second thoughts using that pattern for deploying my custom branding to the OnPrem SharePoint farm.

We were introduced with the Design manager as the best alternative for feature framework based deployment, But it has some serious limitation when deploying those prod or qa environment and others. Due to these limitations I moved back to the feature frameworks based deployment to move the design files between environments.

I had few questions about the PnP that I have typed below, Please share your thoughts if you have any.

- Is this PnP framework something I can trust for the future or will it
  get killed sometime later for a better thing?
- Is feature framework still that better idea for preventing duplicate design packages every time when you deploy to Prod? (Other thing that I have been doing
  deploy to the Network share folder of the QA Server and seemed it might not be that bad)

Sites

- PnP: http://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices
- Control branding deployment: https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/PnP-Add-In-Transformation-Training-module-3-Branding-with-add-in-model

Comment: You can join the Office 365 yammer group and get all the queries related to PnP cleared.